# WP-Markdown treating java generics like HTML tags

Tags: plugins, code

With some Java generic code in a code block, ie:

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

WP-Markdown was treating  as HTML, and no matter what I did, the code above got turned into something like

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList</Integer><Integer>();</Integer>
```

Is there any way to get WP Markdown to behave better with this kind of code? Gist and (clearly) Stackexchange don't have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to fix this for the longest time as well. It seems that the problem is not the rendering, but the editor - when you save, it updates your post.

I found a checkbox under Settings -> Writing called "WordPress should correct invalidly nested XHTML automatically". Unchecking this checkbox fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a shortcode to pass your Java code into that runs `htmlentities` on it. That should get it to display correctly.

```
function clean_java($atts, $content)
{
    return htmlentities($content);
}

add_shortcode('clean_java', 'clean_java');
```

Usage:

```
[clean_java]List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();[/clean_java]
```

WP thinks your Java code is HTML code. Essentially, make it HTML code instead.

Comment: You would think this would happen automatically for a code block...

Comment: Yea, not sure what WP's `code` markdown actually does.